# How to use wp_enqueue_style() in my WordPress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building out my first WordPress site for a client. I really want to use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) for CSS and found a WP plugin named [WP-LESS](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-less/).

Now, I am total WordPress newb, but it appears that this plugin requires me to use a function called [wp_enqueue_style()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) to tell WordPress to process the .less file.

I can't figure out where I use this function. I looked in my header.php file in my theme directory and I see this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
  href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
```

Am I supposed to replace this code with something like this?

```
<?php wp_enqueue_style('mytheme',
  get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/style.less',
  array('blueprint'), '', 'screen, projection'); ?>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Not quite, but almost.  What you want to do is place a function in `functions.php` that queues your script.

So:

```
function addMyScript() {
    wp_enqueue_style('mytheme', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/style.less', array('blueprint'), '', 'screen, projection');
}
add_action('wp_head', 'addMyScript');
```

Then make sure you have `do_action('wp_head');` in your `header.php` file and it should work just fine.

Comment: Yes, but my header is not unique to the homepage. So if i add it in my header, its included in every page.

Comment: Mark, then you'd place the `wp_enqueue_script()` call inside an `if( is_front_page() ) { ... }` conditional statement.  That would cause the script to only be added on the homepage, not on every pace.

Comment: @EAMann it is not really needed to create a function in this case see lime-cat' s answer. I

Answer (score 30):

wp_enqueue_style usage inside of the theme or the plugin:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/my-style.css', false, '1.0', 'all' ); // Inside a parent theme
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/my-style.css', false, '1.0', 'all' ); // Inside a child theme
wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style', plugins_url( '/css/my-style.css', __FILE__ ), false, '1.0', 'all' ); // Inside a plugin
```

Answer (score 5):

Ran into this issue myself, and EAMann's tip almost worked. It might be the version of WordPress (3.4), although I'm not a php developer so I'm not sure, but I needed this below the function instead of what was provided:

```
add_action('wp', 'useLess');
```

Answer (score 5):

Add below function in your theme function.php and you get style and script.

```
<?php
if ( ! function_exists( 'add_script_style' ) ) {
    function add_script_style() {
        /* Register & Enqueue Styles. */

        wp_register_style( 'my-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/my-style.css' );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style' );

        /* Register & Enqueue scripts. */

        wp_register_script( 'my-script', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/my-script.js' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_script_style', 10 );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To make sure the enqueue is done at the proper time use `add_action()`.

So it would be something like the following in `functions.php`:

```php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
  wp_enqueue_style('main-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.less');
});
```

Make sure to have a `<?php wp_head(); ?>` somewhere in your `header.php`.

btw no need to name the function, it can only a potential name clash or typo Preferably use a [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Final remark: Why not compile the `.less` files in the development environment and deploy the resulting `.css` file (minified or otherwise)?

Answer (score 0):

If you enter this code correctly you must be see this function is exist or not in your index.php file wp_head(); & wp_footer();
if is not exist, you need to be add this function in your index file. you need to add this wp_head(); before haed tag, and another one add before body tag.

```php
function load_style() {<br><br>
   wp_register_style( 'my_style', get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/my_style.css' );<br>
   wp_enqueue_style( 'my_style' );<br>
}<br>
// Register style sheet.<br>
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_style' );
```

For more [details](http://beginsall.com/wp-enqueue-style/)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your reply is just code, so please, edit and give format as code. Besides, you should comment one answer with just code in order to explain it, maximum, when there are additional answers.